# Why do I get an error when deserializing a Ruby object?

Tags: ruby, object, serialization

I have the following Ruby map object serialized at one end and received at the other. When received at the target, I need to evaluate it back to the same map object as the original and do some processing.

However, evaluation at the target fails with a "syntax error, unexpected $end" msg.

It fails because the `:application` symbol refers to an `UploadIO` object.

Given that I can only change the code on the target where I receive the serialized object, what is the best way to resolve the issue? Convert the value of `:application` to a string or use some other trick?

```
eval ('
 {"component"=>"CF", 
  "body"=>
    ["PUT", 
     "v2/apps/269e739c-5d08-429c-8682-d3200b79283b/bits", 
     {:payload=>
       {
       :resources=>"[]", 
       :application=>#<UploadIO:0x000000022af330 @content_type="application/zip">
       }
     }
    ]
 }')
```

Comment: Are you expecting to still have access to the zip file?

Comment: no, the zip file is not transferred over, so I think I just need to convert the entire content of `:application` into an equivalent string object before calling `eval` on it.

Comment: But do you *want* it transferred? If you do, then you're going to have to read in the whole zip file and serialize it manually. Once you figure that problem out, you might want to look at Marshal or JSON or XML or some other data interchange format, slinging around strings of Ruby and `eval` is no way to go through life.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reasonably do an `eval` on the string as is, because the `#` is being processed as a comment character. The most straightforward approach would be to go ahead and replace the occurrences of `#<...>` in the string with whatever you want in their place prior to doing the eval.